# How to mock specific function in a module

Tags: reactjs, tdd, jestjs, enzyme

Let's say I have a method `bestFunction` in `module.js` as so:

```js
//module.js

export const bestFunction = x => { 
    return x + 1
}
```

How do I mock `bestFunction` if my code itself is importing as so:

```js
import { bestFunction } from './module.js'
```

Comment: This post is very confusing as title says un-mock but question is about mocking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your test:

```js
  import * as depends from './module.js';

    describe("when testing..", () => {
        beforeEach(() => {
            depends.bestFunction = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => 22); 
        })

        it ('doStuff', () => {
            expect(objectUnderTest.foo()).toEqual('22 red balloons');

        });
    });
```